# Android app back button issue

Tags: bug, android-app

I got a new phone about a month ago but I haven't really installed the SE app on it because I've been on the web version quite often.

Two days ago I decided to install it where I usually access SO. I filter by tags then go to the question to read more about it.

If I either touch the back button or click on the back arrow in the top left, instead of being taken into the list of questions with the tag I've originally chosen, I get taken to the list of tags. What's more is that if I click on the same tag, I have to refresh the list in order to get a proper updated list of questions.

I don't recall this happening before. Has this issue been addressed? I'm using Galaxy S6, not sure if it might be phone specific.

Comment: The bug is there for long time, in several variations.

Comment: @Anna due to tag in title, I didn't notice it was missing from the tags themselves! Good catch.